# Django - Admin Site - how to protect it?

Tags: python, django

I'm wondering if ppl hide admin site? Does anyone put it under different domain? Run it on different server than the main application?

Is it safe to have `/admin/` where everyone can find it, given that it is protected by login screen and permissions test? 
I don't think it's protected from simple brute force attacks, correct me if i'm wrong.

How well django admin site is protected? And what are best practices to protect it?

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857430/how-do-you-guys-protect-django-admin-site) from way back, and accepted answer talks about different apache settings or using VPN, but how would you do it in a cloud like Heroku or AWS?

Comment: Change the URI to your admin in your `urls.py`, and you can use something like [this](https://github.com/Matt-Stevens/django-ssl-admin) to make it SSL only (note: that's one of my projects).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can think of:

- Make sure all staff members have a difficult password (against the brute force you mentioned).
- Moving it to a subdomain such that sessions aren't shared and you need to authenticate separately could actually help a little, in case someone (stupid) leaves their session logged in on a public computer. Having a separate Apache password (as in the question you linked) would be an alternative to this.
- Use HTTPS. If you share sessions with the main site, you need to use https on the main site too. Which would be a good idea anyway.
- Using a VPN could work if you want to restrict IPs, but would require quite some work on your part and on the part of the staff members.

Of these, I would personally say that difficult passwords + https would be enough for many sites. With the added advantage that enforcing difficult passwords is fairly easy (for new passwords) and https is a good idea regardsless of admin site.